# How to get maximum length of an input parameter to an Oracle User Function

Tags: oracle

Is there an easy way to determine the maximum char width of a column that is an input parameter to an Oracle User Function.

Example:

Suppose I have a User Function declaration:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE Function myFn
   ( text_in IN varchar2 )
   RETURN varchar2
IS
...

END;
```

How can I determine within the User Function the maximum width of the input parameter 'text_in' (a column) as passed in the call? I need to determine the maximum length text that myFn can return each time it's called.

Comment: well you could use the all_source system table to get the entire Source; but I don't think this is quite what you're after.

Comment: Looks like it can't be easily done (at least, not without querying system tables).

Comment: Does `text_in` contain the column name?  Or is it the value of a column?  If you have the table and column names, then you just need to query the column's meta-data.

Answer (score 1):

The maximum length of a VARCHAR2 is 32767.

You can get the length for a particular string with the LENGTH(text_in) function.

Comment: Yes, thanks, but that just returns the length of data currently contained in text_in - not the maximum length of text_in.

Comment: @John - To @JeffreyKemp's point, though, the maximum length of any `VARCHAR2` input or output parameter is 32767 bytes.  Of course, it is unlikely that a string that size will ever be passed in or returned.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the table and column names, then you can just query the column's meta-data:

```
select utc.DATA_LENGTH
  from user_tab_columns utc
 where utc.COLUMN_NAME = 'MY_COLUMN'
   and utc.TABLE_NAME = 'MY_TABLE'
```

This assumes that the column data type is CHAR, VARCHAR, or VARCHAR2, of course.

Comment: That doesn't really have anything to do with the length of input parameters to a function, though.  The length of `text_in` is the maximum length of a string (32767).  Even if `myFn` is changed so that the parameter is anchored (i.e. `text_in IN my_table.my_column%type`), the maximum length will be based on the maximum length of a string not the length of `my_table.my_column%type`.

Comment: OK.  I thought that you were looking for a way to validate the length of the input parameter, not just to determine it.